# Netsuite Work Order is showing all work completion records twice in related records

Tags: netsuite

I am an intermediate user of Netsuite.

I am struggeling to figure out why netsuite Work order are showing All "Work Order Completion" record twice in related records.

Same "Work order completion" records are showing in "Assembly built" as well in related records.

Can any make my concepts clear on this. Actually i dont want to see any work order record more than once because it is coming twice in my "Saved search"

Pic is attached to demonstrate.

thanks in advance for help.

[image: Work order completions are coming more that once in netsuite work Order related list]

Comment: That is not really a question programming question. Please have a look at [What topics to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try it at stackexchange site https://serverfault.com/

Comment: when you customized that list you chose a field that shows up twice. This might be a field that represents a multi-select, a line, a field referenced on another related record.